# Can the Spring Boot + Spring Security Keycloak adapters automatically refresh the access token contained in the HttpSession on token expiration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, keycloak, redhat-sso

I am using Keycloak to provide SSO through OIDC for a bunch of applications that belong to the same realm. All of these applications are **confidential** clients that use the **Authorization Code flow**. They use JSP for the views, and all necessary redirects are managed by **Spring Boot and Spring Security Keycloak adapters**.

After successfully logging in I can switch from one application to another correctly (SSO). For each of them, an HttpSession is generated containing a `org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken`. This class, has a details object (`SimpleKeycloakAccount`) with a securityContext (`RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext`) that contains the access token (`tokenString`), id token (`idTokenString`) and refresh token (`refreshTokenString`):

[image]

The contained access token has a 5 minute expiration time. Oddly enough, after this time has passed, although I'm still correctly authenticated in the Spring Boot application, I've checked that **the access token is never refreshed**.

I need to have a valid access token, since some of these applications invoke REST services, secured with the same adapters with bearer only authentication. The problem is I end up having an expired access token and have to deal (manually?) with its expiration.

**Is there a way to make the adapter refresh the access token when it expires or are we expected to do so programmatically?**

**Can you show how to do it?**

Comment: Actually it should work out of the box. In class `RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext` in `getTokenString` method there is refresh token call. Can you debug `getTokenString` to find out at what step it fails to set updated token? Also try to enable debug mode and check logs.